# Regular-ish chipings in slate - weird weathering, hewn or a fossil?

Tags: geology, fossils

When hiking in the Moselvalley (on the [Calmont](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Calmont+Klettersteig/@50.108568,7.1250698,14z/data=!4m6!3m5!1s0x47be397c34e6ff43:0x23896a30bc7c2842!8m2!3d50.1074872!4d7.1252098!16s%2Fg%2F11gvy16vv6), to be precise) I found a slightly rhomboid piece of slate measuring about 10 by 11 cm, with a thickness of ca. 2 to 4 cm.

As can be seen in the first photograph, there's a S-shaped chain of "chippings", which might resemble a tail, a long neck or... I don't know what. Maybe someone sometime was bored and practiced stone hewing.

[image]

The "chippings" are about 3 to 6 mm deep and while not identical, quite similar in shape and size. Their arrangement looks to me rather organic, but I am no expert.

[image]

For completeness, this is the back side of the piece of slate.

[image]

I know that slate deposits tend to contain fossils and wonder if I got lucky, or if I am seeing something that isn't there.

Comment: sedimentary rock+quartz intrusion that is deposited later (i think)than the potential fossil so yes it might very well be a fossil,i have no idea from what.

Comment: It might be a fossil of a worm or a centipede.